# Change C string value with pointer

Tags: c, string, pointers

im trying to change a part of a string using another pointer.
what I have

```
    char** string = (char**) malloc (sizeof(char*));
*string = (char*) malloc (100);
*string = "trololol";

char* stringP = *string;
stringP += 3;
stringP = "ABC";
printf("original string : %s\n\n", *string);
printf("stringP : %s\n\n", stringP);
```

What I get

```
original string : trololol;
stringP : ABC;
```

what I whant is troABCol in both of them :D

I know I have a pointer to a string (char**) because thats what I need in order to do this operation inside a method.

Comment: What is *msg?? Please write the full code.

Comment: In C, you have to copy strings with `strcpy()` or `memmove()` or their various relatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do `strcpy(*string, "trololol")` instead of `*string = "trololol"`;. Your solution brings memory leak, as it replaces the memory pointer allocated by `malloc()` with pointer to data, which contains the pre-allocated "trololol" string.

`strcpy()` copies the pure string pointed to, and instead of `stringP = "ABC";`, you can do `memcpy(stringP, "ABC", 3)` (`strcpy` appends `\0` at the end, whereas `memcpy` copies only data it is told to copy).

Answer (score 0):

Read Amit's answer.  Also, when you write

```
stringP = "ABC";
```

you are just changing the pointer to point at a different string; you are not changing the string it was pointing at.  You should look up `memcpy` and `strcpy`.